# How can I change charset and collation with Django's migrations?

Tags: django

I have a character field that's `utf8` I want it to be `utf8mb4`, how do I accomplish that with Django's migrations?

Comment: Did you mean for that field alone or all character fields? Django's doc mentions a [setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#connecting-to-the-database) but I think this is db wide

Comment: @Sayse a pre-existing field.

Answer (score 2):

Django doesn't have support for different character sets. You tell it `CharField`, it uses Unicode internally, it uses UTF-8 when talking to the RDBMS, and it's the RDMBS's job to convert the strings into the encoding it uses for storage.

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#encoding:

> Django assumes that all databases use UTF-8 encoding.

Note that the thing MySQL calls utf8mb4 is what everyone else (including Django) calls UTF-8, and that what MySQL calls utf8 is a subset of UTF-8 that doesn't exist elsewhere.

So Django doesn't support any messing around with the encodings of char fields of the database. It expects you to create the database with an encoding supporting all Unicode characters, and for the RDBMS to use UTF-8 when communicating with the database client (i.e. with Django).

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about migrating existing databases and is also largely incorrect. Django has never had first order support for utf8mb4, there's no equivalency, there's still a 4 year old issue on the tracker about it but there's still concerns regarding fk length limitations Django isn't handling. You can override the connection encoding in the DATABASE settings through charset specifically for this purpose. You can also just pass along connection init args if you must. I guess I'll just use runPython.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom SQL migration.

1. Create an empty migration with `./manage.py makemigrations <app> --empty --name <a_good_name>`
2. Add a [`migrations.RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) operation to the `operations` list. You can just add the `sql` (and `reverse_sql` if you want it to be reversible). No need to add a state operation.
3. Run `./manage.py migrate`!

You're SQL would look something like:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `my_table`
CHANGE `my_column` `my_column` longtext 
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NULL;'
```